# The upload file could not be moved to wp-content/uploads error

Tags: php, wordpress

While using the 'Ultimate Members' plugin, I am receiving the following error when trying to upload media to my wordpress website:

> The uploaded file could not be moved to wp-content/uploads/2018/09.

Comment: show code and error with more details. without code we can't help you

Comment: Make sure the folder exists and check its permissions

Comment: Yes the folders etc. everything is there, actually the website was running fine and uploading images was working, but when I install the ultimate member plugin, then this problem came.

Comment: And when I deactivate ultimate member plugin then add media works fine, but I need the ultimate plugin too

Comment: Please try to add the code and actual error you are getting, then only StackOverflow community can help you.

Comment: Actually I am getting this error “ The uploaded file could not be moved to wp-content/uploads/2018/09.
“ while trying to upload any new image on the wp-admin.

And I have installed the “Ultimate Members” plugin (https://wordpress.org/plugins/ultimate-member/
). And when I deactivate this plugin then the add media works fine when I activate this plugin then the add media throw the above error.

Hope this is now clear to all, and someone can get me the solution.

Answer (score 0):

This error could be caused by a few things;
Permissions is the most probable answer, your plugin might not have the correct permissions to upload your contents folder.
You will need to go into your file system and change the wp-contents folder and everything within it to 744. If this doesn't work, try 755.

Hope this helps!